# Embed podcast feed in wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, podcast

I have a page in wordpress where I want to embed a player of some sorts that can take the first 3-5 items from a podcast xml feed and embed them in a player with a playlist. Preferable if the title and description can be shown as well.

There is most likely plugins or scripts that does this but I just can't seem to find any. A hint for such a plugin or php script would be lovely.

Update: I found http://www.magicparser.com and used it to parse the feed

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/podcasting/

Wordpress has a great plugin catalog

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question carefully enough.  I don't think this does exactly what you want.  But I'm going to leave the answer up for others.